# Promise undefined after changing to unsigned request

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-js

I have this function:

```
function doChunkInput() {
  console.log('Put Objects Chunk');
  let i = 0;
  let stream = new Readable({
     read() {
       while(i < 10000) {
          if(!this.push("data")) return;
          i++
       }
       this.push(null);
     }
  })

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    Body: stream,
    Key: `myobj`,
  };
  return cos.putObject(params).promise();
}
```

I wanted to change it to do an unsigned request so I now have this:

```
function unauthenticatedRequest(operation, params, callback) {
  var request = cos[operation](params);
  request.removeListener('validate', AWS.EventListeners.Core.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS);
  request.removeListener('sign', AWS.EventListeners.Core.SIGN);
  request.send(callback);
}

function doChunkInput() {
  console.log('Put Objects Chunk');
  let i = 0;
  let stream = new Readable({
     read() {
       while(i < 10000) {
          if(!this.push("data")) return;
          i++
       }
       this.push(null);
     }
  })

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    Body: stream,
    Key: `myobj`,
  };
  unauthenticatedRequest('putObject', params).promise();
}
```

Now when I run it I get this:

```
/Users/paulcarron/git/ibm-cos-sdk-js-basic-test/http-streaming.js:69
  unauthenticatedRequest('putObject', params).promise();
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined
    at doChunkInput (/Users/me/git/basic-test/http-streaming.js:69:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/basic-test/http-streaming.js:72:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: calling `unauthenticatedRequest('putObject', params)` returns undefined - not sure how that relates to code that works since you wrote that function to not return anything - in first code, it's `cos.putObject(params)` that returns an object with a `promise()` method

Comment: perhaps `return request` in your function

Comment: When I change `unauthenticatedRequest('putObject', params).promise();` to `unauthenticatedRequest('putObject', params);`. The request seems to be sending in the way Ihoped but it returns a 403 error. I assume because it is an unsigned request. How can I fix this?